# Django error : global name 'request' is not defined

Tags: django, django-request

I'm getting a little problem with my Django view. I have a function `Identity_FewUpdates` and I get this error : `global name 'request' is not defined`.

It's pretty strange because I have an other function which looks like very similar and I don't get problems up to now.

My function looks like :

```
import requests, os, json, glob
from django.shortcuts import render, reverse, get_object_or_404, render_to_response
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from models import Person, CountryField
from BirthCertificate.models import BirthCertificate
from forms import PersonForm, PersonForm2
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Context
from xhtml2pdf import pisa

import Logger, Search, Folds, Docs, Buffer, EnterSearch

from chartit import DataPool, Chart

from django.db.models import Count
from django_countries import countries

import time
from random import randint
from django.contrib import messages 

import Global_variables

@login_required
def Identity_FewUpdates(requests):

    query_social_number = request.GET.get('social_number')

    if query_social_number :
        query_social_number_list = Person.objects.filter(social_number__icontains=query_social_number)   
        print query_social_number_list 
    else :
        query_social_number_list = Person.objects.none() # == []


    form = PersonForm(request.POST or None, instance = query_social_number_list.first())

    query_job = request.GET.get('job')

    context = {
        "query_social_number" : query_social_number,
        "query_social_number_list" : query_social_number_list,
        "query_job" : query_job,
        "form": form
    }
    return render(request, "Update.html", context)
```

The function is a draft for the moment.
Do you have any idea about this problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django view function takes `request` argument not `requests`.

```
@login_required
def Identity_FewUpdates(request):

    query_social_number = request.GET.get('social_number')
```

Comment: @Deadpool Happens sometimes... https://twitter.com/rajasimon/status/872364753129230336

Comment: Lol it's a joke ? Are you using my case as an example ? ><

Comment: Nope bro! I think he's the reason for confusion isn't it ?

Comment: You're right ;) I was too much carefull about my script wrote inside the function and not to the function herself...

Comment: Try some editor especially https://www.kennethreitz.org/essays/sublime-text-3-heaven this one and with  https://github.com/squ1b3r/Djaneiro